# date time parse error

Tags: c#, datetime-format

I'm using .net Framework 4.0 and developing an console app.

My regional setting are set as en-us.

I'm getting error:

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

on following code.

```
DateTime time = XmlConvert.ToDateTime("2013-11-08T08:08:32+5.5", "yyyy-M-dTH:m:sz");
```

I'm testing my app in windows 2008 R2 server.

Comment: There is a `T` and a `+` in your date. Which one is correct, the example date or the parsing scheme?

Comment: 2013-11-08T08:08:32+5.5 is an example date which I gave before I use the real xml element

Comment: what is the meaning of `+5.5` in your example? It doesn't match with the `stz` part or your parse.

Comment: I did a mistake  on posting the question. sorry for that. The correct one is "yyyy-M-dTH:m:sz"

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code does not account for the `.5` bit (`z` takes care just of the `+5` part without decimals). Corrected version:

```
DateTime time = XmlConvert.ToDateTime("2013-11-08T08:08:32+5.5", "yyyy-M-dTH:m:sz.f");
```

UPDATE

As rightly pointed out by digEmAll via comments, the proposed `.f` correction avoids the problem although does not account for the date properly. The `.f` modifier refers always to a fraction of second, even in case of being located far away from seconds (as in this case). The fractions of `z` have to be provided by relying on the `:` modifier and by converting `z` into `zzz`.

Thus, the aforementioned code represents a practical solution for the OP's conditions (technically speaking, taking a wrong date format as inputs), although does not deliver an accurate result. A pre-modification of the input format would be required in order to accomplish so, that is:

```
string input = "2013-11-08T08:08:32+5.5";
string format = "yyyy-M-dTH:m:sz";
string correctedInput = input;
string correctedFormat = format;
string[] temp = input.Split('.');
if (temp.Length == 2 && temp[1].AsEnumerable().Select(x => char.IsDigit(x)).Count() == temp[1].Length)
{
    correctedInput = temp[0] + ":" + Convert.ToString(Math.Round(60 * Convert.ToDecimal(temp[1]) / 10, 2));
    correctedFormat = "yyyy-M-dTH:m:szzz";
}
DateTime time = XmlConvert.ToDateTime(correctedInput, correctedFormat);
```

Comment: `".f"` means that the final `5` becomes the tenths of seconds (i.e. `time = 8:8:32.5`), is that what the OP wants ?

Comment: @digEmAll why the tenth of the second? I understand that is the tenth of the variable it is is modifying, in this case z (+5). If the DateTime variable does not support this format, at least, it does not trigger an error.

Comment: No, it's always the tenth of seconds of the time. The formatter is not aware of the "variables", it just translates some predefined tokens into something, then it always translates "f" as tenth of seconds ignoring the position. BTW, DateTime supports non integral offsets. For example in this case you should specify it as `+05:50` (read 5 h and 50 min) and set the format specifier to "zzz" ([documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.100%29.aspx))

Comment: @digEmAll OK. Thanks for the info. Actually, I did know already about the ":" option. But as far as "." was a requirement for the OP and, after testing the .f bit, everything worked fine, I thought that my interpretation was right (couldn't imagine that .f affects seconds even in a so "wrong" location). Will edit my answer right away.

Comment: @digEmAll I have updated my answer by bringing your comment into account. Thanks.